# get_class_vars() in an abstract class returns wrong variables

Tags: php, abstract-class, abstract

I coded a bunch of classes extending an abstract class in PHP. The abstract class has variables as well as the class which extends the abstract class.

I would like to create a method inside the abstract class, which return all the class variables of the child classes but don't have to be recoded in every subclass.

This snippet works fine in a subclass in order to get all variables, the ones from the abstract class and the other classes:

```
get_class_vars(get_class($this))
```

However, if I move this snippet to the abstract class, it doesnt work. Here's what I did:

```
public function test($test)
{
    var_dump(get_class($test));
    var_dump(get_class_vars(get_class($test)));
}
```

This code returns the class name of the passed class correctly, but the get_class_vars() does only return the variables of the abstract class, no matter which class is passed here.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. An MRE will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
abstract class Entity
{
protected int $top;

public function test()
    {
        var_dump(get_called_class());
        var_dump(get_class_vars(get_called_class()));
    }
}

class Sub extends Entity
{
    public String $test; // CHANGED FROM PRIVATE TO PUBLIC!
}

$test = new Sub();
$test->test();
```

I found the solution - it was a "private" issue. The variable in the subclass needs to be at least a protected variable in order to be seen from the top class.